# Class.forName() is giving Classnotfound exception when trying to use HiveDriver

Tags: java, database, hive, connection

The problem:

```
try{
   Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have downloaded the necessary jar files and no answer to previous alike questions seemed to work.

I know the program has access to the files because I can import the class.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is the jar file located?

Comment: In a seperate folder that is not in my jdeveloper folder. Could that cause the error? Its in a file under user

Answer (score 0):

Try to include that jar file's in your **build path** or add jar file's to **CLASS_PATH** of your system.

Comment: They are already shown under my classpath. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: @BobDoe do the classes in the jar belong to the classpath after deploying?

Comment: @JimHawkins how you are compiling your code ? I guess, while compiling you are not referring to those jar.

Comment: @Amolb AFAIK, it's not necassary to compile against the database driver class.

Comment: @Amolb When I try the same thing with hadoops configured class it gives no errors. They are at the same location and are called the same way. But hivedriver wont work.